# Trouble generating subtypes: Resulting Pick<T, never> becomes any instead of never. How to avoid?

Tags: typescript

Edit:
I believe the real problem is that there isn't / I don't know a type for an empty object?! The following, surprisingly, is not an error:

```js
const empty = {} as const;
const xx: typeof empty = {
  ho: 'hi'
}
```

while this is

```js
const notEmpty = {
    hasKey: 'andValue'
} as const;

const yy: typeof notEmpty = {
    ho: 'hu' // not assignable
}
```

There is a [github issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/47486) regarding this problem, which people seem not to take very seriously. I believe it is!! It's totally inconsistent behaviour!!!

---

---

I'm trying to build a complex API object with all kinds of properties and functions from a fairly basic input object.

This requires very challenging TypeScript constructs with mapped and conditional types.

I've come pretty far, but am currently challenged by weirdness: I'm using nested utility types at one point, which can result in an effective `Pick<T, never>`. Since none of the keys inside `T` can be assigned to `never` I'd expect the resulting type to be `typeof {}`. Instead, it's `any`.

That is *extremely* unsafe, and currently blows my approach to doing things.

Is there a way to avoid this? Is this a bug, or something that's unavoidable?

Here a simple reproduction:

```js
type Original = {
    ho: string;
    ha: string;
    hu: string;
}

type Derived = Pick<Original, 'ho'>; 

const thisIsFine: Derived = { // works fine, as intended
    ho: 'yes',
    // ha: 'can\'t be assigned'
}

type ShouldBeEmptyObject = Pick<Original, never>;

const shouldntBePossible: ShouldBeEmptyObject = {
    anythingGoes: "that's not cool"
}


// More practical example
type AnyObject = {
  [key: string]: any
}

// I distinguish paremeter from property by checking if key starts with '$'
type ParameterSegments<T extends AnyObject> = Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, `$${string}`>>;
type PropertySegments<T extends AnyObject> = Omit<T, Extract<keyof T, `$${string}`>>;

const inputObject = { // we'll generates subtypes from this
    property1: 'hoho',
    property2: 'haha',
    $parameter7: 'param'
};

const onlyProperties: PropertySegments<typeof inputObject> = { // works fine
    property1: 'juppie', // must be present
    property2: 'juchei', // must be present
    // property3: "can't be assigned, not in inputObject",
    // $parameter7: "can't be assigned, is parameter"
};

const onlyPropertyInput = { // troublemaker
    propertyX: 'XxX'
};

const onlyParameters: ParameterSegments<typeof onlyPropertyInput> = { // SHIT
    jap: 'no',
    $worries: '!',
    anything: 'goes',
    $nothing: 'isRequired'
};
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5#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-DY2dTbAxR8wzOMkjb6B0UO1ZqAAA09nvw3FEYlLNjOvs0BoUoBDYZyLujsfjKkTLLZALTeBgc3d0ezudJwALfKLUBL5cr1aYtfrrEIThcLTQYAEwAHHLw4SqMQgFkw2CQOQUCNKdAErV9SWSOr1YNoBWJFENoAAjDQrAoawKlIfVvxbEAACYAI4DhygKT1lRJdVNQAdgApDaT6MR103VxnEwEANGbI0EGhJtwKNEA23DTtfTnHc9wPYAhwISJojiBJnwCT8SL-ACVgEMAwDI8p2KgOYBFcdp9VKDteMo0BoMsQTzQgBAxKqSTpKJVVaHk0Cqi-H8QAAZlhOpUGaNoOiebpVCOVEbVQZzd33FNgBhEDSCqRCAxQhR0KgGFLOsmTOnslRzE8JV-KDOAsRw84tygAiiL4kAvFQNywnEhhPheNV0F5OAFJMgANADyqpcrsNwi4WjS-1kPi2gaGawNNRojtI3ou0moyrK3NY49omGAAJLwowKFZ0DAACUXg0DPU4xByIsABCJbSBBMEmAApAoTKbySE9FE9qQADPAAJQgABHeVVRUOqgA)

Comment: The definition of `Pick` has a constraint on the 2nd type argument `Pick<T, K extends keyof T>` . Now I don't know the internals of typescript enough to know why `never` works as the 2nd generic argument without erroring outright but I do believe it should not work at all because `never` does not extend the type `keyof T` I would say axiomatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found [this Github issue](https://github.com/typescript-eslint/typescript-eslint/issues/2063#issuecomment-675156492) helpful.

> The type {} doesn't mean "any empty object", it means "any non-nullish value".

Since the `{}` type does not prevent us from assigning properties to it, we should use a different type to represent an empty object. The author of the linked comment offers an alternative:

```
type EmptyObject = Record<string, never>; // or {[k: string]: never}

const a: EmptyObject = { a: 1 };  // expect error
const b: EmptyObject = 1;         // expect error
const c: EmptyObject = () => {};  // expect error
const d: EmptyObject = null;      // expect error
const e: EmptyObject = undefined; // expect error
const f: EmptyObject = {};        // NO ERROR - as expected
```

This `Record` type only allows empty objects. We can use this for the types `ParameterSegments` and `PropertySegments`.

```
type ParameterSegments<T extends AnyObject> = 
  {} extends Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, `$${string}`>>
    ? Record<string, never>
    : Pick<T, Extract<keyof T, `$${string}`>>

type PropertySegments<T extends AnyObject> = 
  {} extends Omit<T, Extract<keyof T, `$${string}`>>
    ? Record<string, never>
    : Omit<T, Extract<keyof T, `$${string}`>>
```

For both types we can check if the result would be an empty object and return `Record<string, never>` if that is the case.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.5.5&ssl=36&ssc=46&pln=27&pc=1#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-3rRtQAAJhAjgOHKApfTAaVaTlBQAHYQNQmU+jEVhCCcZ8oGcTAQA0KDAIQUpgLrACmxAFsVXbfQJWLV930-YAvwHIFIIYoCQJWAQwDAGikIE6CQDgywRO0MgIAQcoHAInFiNcTiP0NYAYN-UgULQ2V5WwyxcNpfDCI0loyIoqimxo2hZMowSmKVFi1XYj0tO4mC+KIKTAJAOiLBEsSJIg0h-2k2TQoEBSlJU-pCMfazSNQciXOkrxUDfHj9JIaKgoADRA4qqWKySDKKxjYoQ9BLKfVxbKlGUMLgWg6Na9D5WYttPKGYsWvs0Acry3iwkiaJhgACS8dVkJq2DYXQDIVCxNSmpsjK7Ncsb3z0vAAqikaQFKyxysq5KtvSzKjPapys3u3r3P6tjBo9Ya9tyg7-Km945oWjMVnQMAQJRKqSF9OI4EQaFLAAQkhqAQTBJgQKQKEykiqGUTRpAQM8WMAEcBAQOBemuwggA)